# How can i solve this error in android studio? java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'recycler_food_list'

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android studio and i'm not sure what was going on with it. How can I solve this error?

In the logcat, it mentioned that I required a view for recycler_food_list which apparently I had already coded into the foodlistfragment.java.

**Logcat**

```
2021-06-15 11:11:57.189 5164-5164/com.android.ridefun E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.ridefun, PID: 5164
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'recycler_food_list' with ID 2131231048 for field 'recycler_food_list' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
    at butterknife.internal.Utils.findRequiredView(Utils.java:84)
    at butterknife.internal.Utils.findRequiredViewAsType(Utils.java:96)
    at com.android.ridefun.ui.foodlist.FoodListFragment_ViewBinding.<init>(FoodListFragment_ViewBinding.java:21)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:170)
    at com.android.ridefun.ui.foodlist.FoodListFragment.onCreateView(FoodListFragment.java:44)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**fragment_food_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_food_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout_food_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
app:cardElevation="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_food_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#AA333639"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_food_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name of food"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_food_price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$0"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_fav"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_border_24"
            app:tint="@color/white"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_quick_cart"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"
            app:tint="@color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**FoodListFragment.java**

```
public class FoodListFragment extends Fragment {

private FoodListViewModel sendViewModel;

Unbinder unbinder ;
@BindView(R.id.recycler_food_list)
RecyclerView recycler_food_list;

LayoutAnimationController layoutAnimationController;
MyFoodListAdapter adapter;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sendViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(FoodListViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this,root);
    initViews();
    sendViewModel.getMutableLiveDataFoodList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), foodModels -> {
        adapter = new MyFoodListAdapter(getContext(),foodModels);
        recycler_food_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        recycler_food_list.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);
    });
    return root;
}

private void initViews() {
    recycler_food_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler_food_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    layoutAnimationController = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.layout_item_from_left);
}
```

**MyFoodListAdapter**

```
public class MyFoodListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyFoodListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<FoodModel> foodModelList;

public MyFoodListAdapter(Context context, List<FoodModel> foodModelList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.foodModelList = foodModelList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
    .inflate(R.layout.layout_food_item,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(context).load(foodModelList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.img_food_image);
    holder.txt_food_price.setText(new StringBuilder("$")
    .append(foodModelList.get(position).getPrice()));
    holder.txt_food_name.setText(new StringBuilder("")
    .append(foodModelList.get(position).getName()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return foodModelList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private Unbinder unbinder;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_food_name)
    TextView txt_food_name;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_food_price)
    TextView txt_food_price;
    @BindView(R.id.img_food_image)
    ImageView img_food_image;
    @BindView(R.id.img_fav)
    ImageView img_fav;
    @BindView(R.id.img_quick_cart)
    ImageView img_cart;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);`, not inflating your `R.layout.fragment_food_list`. You'll need to inflate the right layout to find your Recycler view.

Comment: Thanks, error solved. Can't believe how stupid I am :D.

Comment: @LeeZiJie, if ianhanniballake's recommendation solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as the solution (The tick underneath the up and down arrow on the left.)